# How to pass arguments from docker-compose to Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, arguments, dockerfile

I have a small Dockerfile in the folder `backend`:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG FTP_IP
ARG MONGO_IP
ARG QUORUM_IP

RUN apk add --update openjdk8 && mkdir /var/backend/
RUN apk update
COPY license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /var/backend/
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "-Dspring.quorum.host=${QUORUM_IP}", "-Dspring.ftp.server=${FTP_IP}", "-Dspring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGO_IP}","/var/backend/license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]
```

And even smaller docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  generator:
    build: backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

I am starting this with a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FTP_IP=$1 MONGO_IP=$2 QUORUM_IP=$3 docker-compose up -d
```

Like this:

```
start-backend.sh 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 http://localhost:22000
```

But it is not working at all... when I call `docker inspect` on the created container I get:

```
"Id": "bd3e05a8fffba6bb7b5c650d1f48c0ed13dca9108e01e1a82ec534a5f19d4393",
        "Created": "2019-05-29T09:38:32.723414205Z",
        "Path": "java",
        "Args": [
            "-jar",
            "-Dspring.quorum.host=${QUORUM_IP}",
            "-Dspring.ftp.server=${FTP_IP}",
            "-Dspring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGO_IP}",
            "/var/backend/license-system-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
        ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See Args in [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

Answer (score -1):

in your script start-backend.sh you have used variables FTP_IP,MONGO_IP and QUORUM_IP which are local to the script, export them as env variables and it will work.

Keep in mind Values in the shell take precedence over those specified in the .env file and dockerfile so you might be overwriting the values defined there ...